# Crop to exclude any transparency on a ragged edge

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I have a square image with a ragged edge: the transparent pixels outside the image "weave" in and out towards the image center, within some unknown range. This range may be different for each side.

[image: Ragged edge]

Is there an algorithm that would crop the image to the largest size possible with no transparent pixels remaining? I can think of an iterative one: start with a small cropping square in the center. If no transparent pixels are detected, start again but enlarge the cropping square by 1 pixel. Then repeat. Once you detect transparent pixels after cropping, go back one step and save the result.

Comment: I assume "transparency" to be some alpha channel with values less than `255`!? Just find the maximum rectangle for pixels with alpha channel value of `255`. Depending on the language, that's a few lines of code (Python with NumPy for example). Maybe some additional lines are needed, if the output must be a square, too, but that's also not that hard, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There is an obvious algorithm that comes to mind:

- Find `y* = min_y {(x,y) : P(x,y) is transparent }`, where `P(x,y)` is the pixel at coord `(x,y)` then crop the image `[0,y*]` (assuming the image starts at zero at the bottom, and that transparent pixels always happen at the top of the image.)

Note that this algorithm has serious downsides, if `y*` happens to be very close to `0` because of an errant transparent pixel, you will end up cropping almost your entire image.

If you want a more robust solution, I believe you will have to frame this problem as an optimization problem and solve it, allowing for some errant transparent pixels to be masked instead of cropped. The algorithm that would do well for you would be an energy-based formulation which could be solved using graph-cuts. For example, see the [GrabCut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_cuts_in_computer_vision) algorithm.

If you know your requirements and how bad your data can get you can make a judgment call for how involved you want to make your solution, but at this point I would highly recommend clarifying the requirements of your solution as well as how bad your data can get.